# Problem with resetting Simply Tabletz tablet, no reset or volume buttons

Tags: factory-reset

I have a tablet that was marketed by simply tablets, I have had it for about a year and it has worked great, until two days ago, then all of a sudden I get the start screen that says simply tablets and that's it,  if a tablet has no reset button and no volume buttons, how can you do a hard reset?